# resttemplate.exchange throwing Exception

Tags: spring-boot, rest, resttemplate

I am trying to call a 3rd party api to register player using REST API call which returns return the response from a 3rd party API.

I am using resttemplate.exchange() method for calling the API.

My service implementation is as below.

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<?> createGamePlayerResponse(@Valid GamePlayerRegisterRequest playerRegisterRequest,
        String language) {
    
    logger.info("Getting Information from Game for Player Details {}", playerRegisterRequest.phone);
    String endpoint = "/player_register";
    String signature;
    try {
        String jsonString = objectMapperUtill.getObjectMapperObject().writeValueAsString(playerRegisterRequest);
        logger.info("Sending Player Register Request object to game : {}",jsonString);
        signature = getSHA256Hash(endpoint);

    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        logger.info("Exception Occured on creating topup Signature, {}", e.getMessage());
        throw new CustomException(e.getMessage());
    }

    logger.info("Generated Signature value:  {}", signature);
    

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + gameApikey);
    headers.set("Accept", "application/json");
    headers.set("Charset", "utf-8");
    headers.set("X-Request-Signature", signature);
    if(language != null) {
        headers.set("Accept-Language", language);
    }
    
    HttpEntity<GamePlayerRegisterRequest> entity = new HttpEntity<GamePlayerRegisterRequest>(playerRegisterRequest, headers);

    try {
        logger.info("Entity body "+entity.getBody());
        ResponseEntity<GamePlayerRegisterResponse> gamePlayerRegisterResponse = restTemplate.exchange(gameEndpoint + endpoint,
                HttpMethod.POST, entity, GamePlayerRegisterResponse.class);
        logger.info(gamePlayerRegisterResponse.toString());
        if (gamePlayerRegisterResponse.getStatusCodeValue() == 200) {
            try {
                logger.info("After player register response from Game: {}",objectMapperUtill.getObjectMapperObject().writeValueAsString(gamePlayerRegisterResponse));
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                logger.info("After player register response from Game object JsonProcessingException : {}",e.getMessage());
            }

            return gamePlayerRegisterResponse;
        }
    } 
    
    catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
        //Gson g = new Gson();
        logger.info("Register Player got some Exception : {} "+e);
//          GameFailureResponse response = g.fromJson(e.getResponseBodyAsString(), GameFailureResponse.class);
//          logger.info("ERROR Response Code: {} ", response.getCode());
//          logger.info("ERROR Response Message: {}", response.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(e, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }

    return null;
}
```

However I am getting below exception when calling the api.

```
            2022-01-03 15:10:44.407--[gameplan_dev]-- INFO--  c.e.m.service.impl.GameServiceImpl     : Register Player got some Exception : {} org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request
            2022-01-03 15:10:44.460--[gameplan_dev]--ERROR--  o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class java.lang.Throwable]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest["mostSpecificCause"])] with root cause

             com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest["mostSpecificCause"])
             at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)
             at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1191)
             at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter._handleSelfReference(BeanPropertyWriter.java:944)
             at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:721)
             at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:721)
             at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:166)
             at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
             at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
             at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1433)
             at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:921)
             at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:287)
             at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104)
             at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:295)
             at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:226)
             at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)
             at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:124)
             at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)
             at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
             at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
             at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
             at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
             at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
             at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
             at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
             at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
             at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
             at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
             at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
             at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
             at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
             at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
             at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
             at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
             at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
             at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
             at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
             at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
             at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
             at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
             at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
             at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
             at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
             at com.gameplan.merchantapp.jwt.filter.AuthRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthRequestFilter.java:104)
             at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
             at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
             at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
             at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
             at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92)
             at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
             at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
             at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
             at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
             at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
             at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
             at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
             at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
             at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
             at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
             at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
             at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
             at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
             at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
             at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
             at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
             at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
             at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
             at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
             at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108)
             at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
             at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
             at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
             at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
             at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
             at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
             at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
             at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
             at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
             at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579)
             at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
             at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Request your help in resolving this.